# Confusion about how to implement BeginInvoke

Tags: c#

I  am required to populate  treeview from  my file system structure. and  my code  works without  any problems.However  when I try to populate  "C"drive This takes a lot time.So I have decided to use BackroundWorker.The problem I am getting this exception below.

Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action.

I have searched for a solution and add this statement

`CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`

It didnt worked.So I have searched for Asyncron programming and tried to implement  begin invoke I coudnt  do it now i'm more confused

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Is the problem to update a `Control` from a different thread?

Comment: How did you try to implement `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: BackgroundWorker won't help you at all. Loading a lot of data to a UI control always happens on the UI thread. Besides, it's the *loading* that takes a lot of time. Wherever you run it, it will still take a lot of time. Reduce the amount of data you load instead, using virtualization techniques, loading nodes *only* when a treeview gets expanded etc

Comment: The question you should maybe be asking is why does it take so long?  What is it you are loading for each item?  COuld it be made more efficient.  Are you loading the entire drive when you could just load each node as it is opened?

Comment: Does your TreeView support data binding? Such controls usually also support data virtualization and/or lazy loading. Which control are you using?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos commented, you may have design problem. How long it takes to load data and how do you populate data? `Invoke` will only solve performance issue if *processing* takes long (loading of data or you need additional job to run for each item). So what takes time: loading data or `AddManyItems`? If loading of data, then loading can occurs in another thread (while control is blank) and then you call `AddManyItems` once. If you e.g have many items and add them individually via `AddOneItem`, then solution is different: suspend *repainting*, search for `BeginUpdate`, `SuspendLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method to switch the thread more or less automatically.

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this ISynchronizeInvoke iSyncInvoke, Delegate iAction, object[] args = null)
{
    if (iSyncInvoke.InvokeRequired)
        iSyncInvoke.Invoke(iAction, args);
    else
        iAction.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```

Then, you can use this extension method for controls to call a delegate on the correct thread as follows.

```
Control SomeControl;
Action iAction = () =>
{
    // do something with control
}
SomeControl.InvokeIfRequired(iAction);
```

Comment: This won't fix the real problem though.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Am I missing something?

Comment: The OP's real problem is loading a lot of data to a treeview, most of which won't even be displayed. Trying to do this from another thread will only make it slower. At best, it won't freeze the UI, but only if each node is loaded with a separate BeginInvoke (with the corresponding overhead). If all data is loaded at once, the UI will still freeze